# PHP send how many multiple email addresses?

Tags: php, email

How many multiple email addresses in single email?

For Example:

```
$to = array(
  "test@gmail.com",
  "test1@gmail.com",
  "test2@gmail.com",
  "test3@gmail.com",
  "test4@gmail.com",
  "test5@gmail.com",
  // more emails
);
$email_to = implode(',', $to); // your email address
$email_subject = "Contact Form Message"; // email subject line
$thankyou = "thankyou.htm"; // thank you page
```

So, My questions is how many email addresses are attached in single mail? is there any limit?

Answer (score -1):

According to the following link you can send a limit of 100 recipients at a time.

https://help.1and1.com/e-mail-and-office-c37589/1and1-mail-basic-c37590/using-the-product-c85088/what-are-the-mass-mailing-limits-a594972.html

Comment: I believe that referes to 1&1's servers only, but the point is: each provider gives you a quota of email you can send daily (Google does that too, I believe it's 100 or 500, can't remember).

Comment: Look in [Simple Mail Transfer Protocol specification](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5321#section-4.5.3.1.8)